# Running multiple sets of docker services in parallel

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We develop and host a few large applications. 
Each application consists of a (non-dockerized) TSQL DB and a Web server. On top of that, there are a number of docker services (like data caching, full text search, geocoding, messaging, etc.) which we dockerized.

We now have about 10 of these applications running (1 TSQL, 1 Web server, ~10 docker containers), all of which are used by a specific customer each. We are plannig to ramp these to about 20 applications.

Now, how should we best manage the docker containers? So far, we start them using a mixture of shell scripts and docker-compose.
I started looking into kubernetes and docker swarm, but these seem to be targeted at running and scaling a single application. However, I would like to use the same set of configurations and parameterize them to 10-20 different systems.

What is the default (or clever) way to configure a set of services (e.g. data-cache, fulltext-search, geocode, messaging) and easily start multiple instances of these sets, each with some customer-specific parameters?

(I did browse the web for some time now, but it seems to me I am missing some tool or step so far)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy the same service with different environment variables on a different docker "stack" using docker swarm.

You can define them as a single `docker-compose.yml` file or multiple files(probably better). Then run
`docker swarm init` and `docker stack deploy service_group1`, `docker stack deploy service_group2` etc. 
The issue you might run into is that the same docker network might be used by the same `docker-compose.yml` file, you probably want to avoid that by providing the different compose files with different network names and volumes so that there is no cross talk.

Comment: Collision of networks will only affect networks created outside the docker stack. A network declared in a docker-compose.yml will be private to the stack. Though, the docker engine will see the same network as "{stack}_{network}".  The command `envsubst` from the `gettext` os package allows simple templating: `export ${variable used in mytemplate}; envsubst < mytemplate | docker stack deploy -c - ${stackname}`. It reduces the challenge to keep different stacks in sync ;)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I guess I need to restructure our setup, use separate build directories, a local repository and a new directories to actually make this work. I could use some kind of templating system to generate the configuration for new sets of services.